# Issue with Application ID URI in Azure AD App registration , while using Terraform

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to modify my application identifier URI from the format :
"`https://app-contoso.api-qa.contoso.onmicrosoft.com`" to the format "`api://(app id)`"
I am using Terraform to do this.
So if i just use :

```
application_identifier_uris   = [format("api://%s", random_uuid.contoso-api-app.result)]
```

i get a random id and not the actual app ID.
How do i ensure that i get the actual App ID in the format "api://(app ID)"
I have to use a random uuid as i get a cyclic error in Terraform if i refer the output of the app ID from my application module.

I am using our own application module to do app registration

Comment: hello @pallab, random_uuid will not give a newly created guid .. you should use app id .. but as you are getting issue .. let me check and get back here.. Can you share the module which are using .. so that i can test it

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT Before sharing the code i found this, please take a look at this link :https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azuread/issues/428

Comment: You are correct @pallab, I don't think it is possible at the time of creation to provide appid there as the app id will only be generated after the creation and you can't provide it inside the identifier_uri's block for azure ad application

Comment: You can use CLI or powershell to perform the operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i get a random id and not the actual app ID. How do i ensure that i
> get the actual App ID in the format "api://(app ID)" I have to use a
> random uuid as i get a cyclic error in Terraform if i refer the output
> of the app ID from my application module.

You are generating a ***random GUID*** and assigning the value there , so for that reason you will be getting random ID and not the actual app ID. As for the **Cyclic Error** you will be receiving error something like below image if you use a reference to AppID as the application is getting created the same time when you referencing it so after creation only the application id will be usable or identified.

[image]

So, the above is not possible from terraform for now ,as you already know there has been a ***Feature flag or Enhancement*** raised for the same in this [**Github Issue**](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azuread/issues/428).

---

For solution you can use other management tools like `Powershell/Azure-CLI` to update the `identifier uri's`.

After Azure AD application is created from terraform you can use [**AzureAD**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/set-azureadapplication?view=azureadps-2.0) Modules or [**az ad app**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app?view=azure-cli-latest#az_ad_app_update) CLI module to update the application programatically.

**For your use case Powershell script will be something like below:**

```
Connect-AzureAD
$app= Get-AzureADApplication -Filter "DisplayName eq 'ansumanterraformtest'"
$appobjectid = $app.ObjectId
$appId = $app.AppId
Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $app.ObjectId -IdentifierUris "api://$appId"
```

**Outputs:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this problem is to use key text instead of using the id, which can even be parameterized by variables.

```
  identifier_uris  = [var.app-env == "production" ? "api://${var.empresa}${var.app-name}" : "api://${var.empresa}${var.app-name}-${var.app-env}"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add identifier uri as follows:

```
resource "azuread_application" "api_ad" {
  # Your configuration
}

resource "azuread_application_identifier_uri" "api_ad" {
  application_id = azuread_application.api_ad.id
  identifier_uri = "api://${azuread_application.api_ad.client_id}"
}
```